# Access an object inside another object returns cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a trivial problem but I can't solve for some reason.

I have an object, which is a return request from an API:

```
state = { 
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,CA&appid=${appkey}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        // .then((data) => {
        //  console.log(data);
        // })
        .then(data => this.setState({data}))

    }
```

and:

```
render() {
const weather = this.state.data
console.log(weather.main);
```

The first part is what comes first before the react component. I was able to fetch an object and then I create a variable (const) which return another object, in this case:

```
{feels_like: 271.85
temp_min: 272.15
temp_max: 276.48
pressure: 1027
humidity: 97}
```

For my ignorance, the weird part is that, if I try to access for example the first value (feels_like) in this way:

```
weather.main.feels_like
```

it will throw an error which is Cannot read property 'feels_like' of undefined.

Now, I tried to loop through the object but it didn't work and I tried to access the property with a different syntax but still, it threw an error.

Am I missing something?

The goal is to create a component like that:

```
console.log(this.state.data);
 const weather = this.state.data;
 return (

  <div>
  <div key={weather.id}>
  <h3>Library Product of the Week!</h3>
  <h4>{weather.name}</h4>
  <h4>{weather.main.temp}</h4>
  <h4>{weather.main.feels_like}</h4>
  <h4>{weather.main.temp_min}</h4>
  <h4>{weather.main.temp_max}</h4>
  <h4>{weather.main.pressure}</h4>
  <h4>{weather.main.humidity}</h4>
  </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

That's the entire code:

```
import React from 'react'
 import { render } from 'react-dom'

 const appkey = 'xx';

 class Message extends React.Component {

    state = { 
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,CA&appid=${appkey}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        // .then((data) => {
            //  console.log(data);
            // })
            .then(data => this.setState({data}))

        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            console.log("The component just updated")
        }

        render() {
            console.log(this.state.data);
            const weather = this.state.data;
            return (

                <div>
                <div key={weather.id}>
                <h3>Library Product of the Week!</h3>
                <h4>{weather.name}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.temp}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.feels_like}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.temp_min}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.temp_max}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.pressure}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.humidity}</h4>
                </div>
                </div>
                )
        }
    }

    render(
        <Message />, 
        document.getElementById('root')
        )
```

Comment: When and where are you trying to access `object1.main.feels_like`?

Comment: It looks like `data` is initialized to an array, but accessed as an object. Which do you expect it to be? Could you provide the commented out console log of `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you provided it seems that you're already accessing the data before it has been saved to the state for the first time. So you're trying to get the feels_like value from your empty array which is your initial state.

In order to fix it you should check if your data is present before using it in your render method

EDIT:

For some reason the API key didn't work for me and the docs mentioned it could take a few hours before it will work so I won't be able to test that for you. But [the code sandbo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bush-hsdyr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)x checks if the data is present before rendering it. And it will render some text if the data is uninitialized. Hope this helps!

Comment: I put the entire code in order to explain what it happens.. actually, it works if I tried to access the first level of the object. that's the part that it is making me crazy

Comment: Well that seems strange and shouldn't be possible as far as I know. Either way you should check that the information is present before using the data in the render component. And I expect that it will resolve your error. Or at the least resolve an error you'll be receiving after fixing this one.

Comment: It actually works, but only for the first level, you can try with a apikey

Comment: This is why it very odd for me that I cannot access the second level of the object

Comment: Object
temp: 274.19feels_like: 271.6temp_min: 272.04temp_max: 275.93pressure: 1027humidity: 97__proto__: Object

That's the result of

const weather2 = this.state.data;
console.log(weather2.main);

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not near my desktop so I won't be able to try it for the moment. I'll check back later when I'm near mine if you were able to resolve it and otherwise try and help you

Comment: I just tried it again with a valid API key and the data is rendered as expected. So check the code sandbox and implement it. This should resolve your issues

Comment: Great catch! It works! So essentially the missing part is the conditional statement because before to return the jsx the system hasn't set up the variable weather yet? In any case, great catch!